# Error when using binding_of_caller gem with Rubinius 2.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubinius

Using binding_of_caller in the gem list on a Rubinius (2.1.0) environment triggers the following error, once the server launch:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `caller_locations' on an instance of ActionController::RoutingError.
```

(Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8a7afzgwb5aq2k/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-13%20at%2010.58.36.png?dl=0?dl=1)

Here is the Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end
```

This is caused by binding_of_caller because when removed, everythings works fine.

Do you have any idea of how to still work with binding_of_caller in rbx or do I have to drop it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubinius supports [`#caller_locations`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/6098b87265a0c2420e51b8f804943caee345ae16/kernel/common/kernel.rb#L276) since the `2.4.0` version. The `2.1.0` is really old (Oct 18, 2013), I would suggest to upgrade straight to `2.4.1`.

Comment: Thanks Jiří, you're right. Upgrading to `2.4.1` fixed the issue.